# SVM machine learning - How to define the target in the training set?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, training-data

I am working on a project where I have to implement SVM machine learning algorithm. I am trying to predict the forearm movement intention. I am using accelometer (attached to my forearm) for measuring the angle change for x,y,z axes. I have never used machine before. The problem I am having is I do not exactly know how to structure the training set. I know the angle changes for each of the axis and I know i.e if `x=45` degrees, `y = 65` degrees, `z=30` degrees gesture performed i performed is flexion. I would like to implement 3 gestures.So the data I am having is :

```
x     y     z      Target
20    60    90     flexion   
100   63    23     internal rotation    
89    23    74     twist
```

.
.
.
.

I have a file with around 2000 entries. I know, I have to normalize the training set so the data are scaled. I would like to scale it so they are in range `[0.9, 0.1]`. The problem is that I do not know how to represent the target in my training set. Can I just use random numbers as 1 for flexion, 2 for internal rotation, 3 for twist??

Also once the training is completed, can I do the predictions based on values for x,y,z only?? without having to supply the target value. Is my understanding correct??

Comment: Do you have to use SVM?

Comment: You might have better luck in the Cross Validated community for this question.

Comment: I was advised to use SVM... What is Cross Validated community???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suggest that you *not* scale or code your data.  Leave it in human-readable form.  Rather, write front-end routines to perform these tasks, and back-end routines to reverse the process.  Also have internal routines that can display the data in the internal forms.  Doing these up front will greatly enhance your debugging later on.

Yes, you will likely want to code your classifications as 1, 2, 3.  Another possibility is to have a "one-hot" ordered triple: (1,0,0) or (0,1,0) or (0,0,1).  However, most SVM algorithms are set up for scalar output.  Also, note that the typical treatment for a multi-class algorithm is to run three separate SVM calculations, "one against all".  For each class, you take that class as "plus" data and all the others as "minus" data.

Scaling data is important for regression convergence.  If you're building your SVM via complete and direct computation of the support vectors, you don't need to scale numbers that are in compatible ranges, such as these.  If you're doing it by some sort of iterative approximation, you still won't need it for this data -- but keep it in mind for the future.

Yes, prediction gives only the inputs: x, y, z.  It will *return* the target classification.  That's the purpose of supervised learning: summarize experience to classify the future.

Comment: scaling data is important for SVM too as this is not affine transformation invariant method. Consequenlty different scales means different results, and this is not about solvers but SVM cost itself. Furthermore, there is no point in any classes transformation - neither encoding as 1,2,3 or one-hot is needed as SVM is a binary model, which will not care about what you call your label.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  Some of the algorithms I work with insist on coding the labels as integers.  If that restriction isn't in the OP's algorithm, then it certainly doesn't make sense to artificially code them.

Comment: of course many things might be implementation specific, simply for SVM there is no point in any **particular** coding despite the one needed for a particular library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Very helpful.. But I did not get this part: Also, note that the typical treatment for a multi-class algorithm is to run three separate SVM calculations, "one against all". For each class, you take that class as "plus" data and all the others as "minus" data. I am sorry but I just cant get it

Comment: Research "SVM" + "one vs all".  There are plenty of hits.  Briefly, you train once for each class:  re-code that class as "1", the others as "0", and then train the SVM model.  When you've completed that for all three classes, you then resolve the overlaps or gaps between the models you found (usually by taking a "closest" score, sometimes weighted for class size).